# Links inside email message body

Tags: ios, xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, openurl

I need to modify an existing project. In this project there are several (many) places where the app sends an email with preset text within it. The used function is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:emailString]];
```

Which obviously opens iOS Mail, ready to send the message.
Now I need to include links in the body of the messages. Is it possible to do it without switching to MFMailComposeViewController in all that places? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this document - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007892-SW1

The short answer, yes, you can pre-populate the body of the message by adding a `body` parameter to the URL (i.e `mailto:john@apple.com?body=This%20goes%20to%20body`). Notice though, that the string has to be properly escaped, which you can do easily with the help of NSString's `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

I assume that any URL in the body that looks like a URL will be converted into a link by Mail app itself - not sure about that, test it out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed it does, I mean I managed to have the body pre-populated, and any address such as www.mysite.com is converted to a link by Mail. What I need to achieve is have a link, such as "Visit our site". Using MFMailComposeViewController you can do it via html I guess.

Comment: Yes, that is something you have to handle with HTML, if the answer helped, mark it as the accepted.

Comment: It was easier than I thought, in fact HTML, embedded in emailString,  just worked. There is some wrong information posted around stating that the openURL way doesn't allow to use html. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

it is very simple.
Each html tag should appended, use front slash before double quote in the url beginning and end
Example :

```
    NSString *bodyText =@"<html>";
    bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@"<head>"];
    bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@"</head>"];            
    bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@"<body>"];
    bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@"<a     href=\"http://www.devaski.com\">My blog"];
    bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@"</a>"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:bodyText isHTML:YES];
```